# How to pass custom client to Golang oauth2.Exchange

Tags: go, oauth-2.0

The documentation for oauth2.Exchange at https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#Config.Exchange says:

> The HTTP client to use is derived from the context. If a client is not provided via the context, http.DefaultClient is used.

Now I have created a http.Client with my own settings.  How do I get the oauth2.Exchange function to use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `oauth2` package defines [the following variable](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#pkg-variables):

> ```
> var HTTPClient internal.ContextKey
> ```
>
> HTTPClient is the context key to use with golang.org/x/net/context's WithValue function to associate an *http.Client value with a context.

Use the above variable as the context key when constructing the context to pass to [`Exchange`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#Config.Exchange):

```
client := &http.Client{
    // TODO
}
parent := oauth2.NoContext()
ctx := context.WithValue(parent, oauth2.HTTPClient, client)
tkn, err := c.Exchange(ctx, code)
```